# collectionFS: Images not defined

Tags: meteor

I'm trying collectionFS (v 0.4.3) for the first time with the default pattern but with no luck:

I created a file in /models: collection_fs.js

```
var Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});
```

Then I added a template to my form events: upload_form.coffee

```
Template.uploadForm.events "change .myFileInput": (event, template) ->
  FS.Utility.eachFile event, (file) ->
    Images.insert file, (err, fileObj) ->
```

But it keeps telling me:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Images is not defined
```

I know that collection_fs.js runs (checked with console.log). If I'm not wrong, a variable with var in front has the global scope. So I don't understand what's wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your collection is defined local. If you remove the keyword var from your collection than you can use the collection globally.

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});
```